# Mod_rewrite rules herierarchy

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one line of code that uses mod_rewrite to pull up results from a database as such:

`example.com/anytext/itemid`  to use the following URL: `example.com/item.php?id=itemid`

a simple rewrite. however, I want to make a rule that is superior to it. Follow along to see what I mean:

.htaccess file example:

```
RewriteRule ^products/[^/]+/(.*)$    products/item.php?id=$1 [L]
```

this rule tells `example.com/products/anytext/itemid`  to use `item.php` to display using last portion of URL after the "/", which is the item ID.

HOWEVER, I want some URLs to be redirected instead of re-written. For example:

`products/green-dress/4023` to become:

`products/green-dress-with-stain/4023`
without the rewrite rule kicking in!

Now, I have tried a simple 301 redirect in the .htaccess, BUT it somehow interfers with the rewrite rule.

instead of going to

`products/green-dress-with-stain/4023` it goes to:

`products/green-dress-with-stain4023?id=4023`

See how the URL at the end gets a variable? Weird!

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Mod_alias (`Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` directives, for example) has precedence over mod_rewrite. You can use them to make sure they are parsed and executed first in the .htaccess file. The position inside the file is irrelevant.

Comment: When I do "redirect 301 /green-dress/4052 /green-dress-with-stain/4052" the url becomes: example.com/green-dress-with-stain/4052?id=4052" ...  I don't understand why it adds the ID variable at the end... weird!

Comment: @faa my guess is because of the rewrite rule interfering with the redirect rule...

Comment: Sure. It is the next one, but the first one is always the `Redirect` directive. It's hard to guess what you want unless yo give some examples and a description of the whole process. Maybe you want to update your question with that information..

Comment: @faa made it more clear now, i hope...

Comment: I think it's clear. You want to capture the itemID and pass it to a script, except in some cases. But, how many of these `products/green-dress/4023` exceptions are there and how can be identified? There should be a pattern to make a single rule, otherwise they have to be hardcoded in several rules.

Comment: @foo well, finding the changes is up to me, and I have already made a script to check daily for updates and those updates can be added to the .ht file. I would remove lines of redirection after 30 days (i'm assuming the search engines would have found my redirects by then)

Answer (score 0):

The rules in your `.htaccess` file are executed in order, so if you need that one rule take precedence over other, simply put it first in the file.

Comment: how do i make it not redirect 301 permanent redirects? i basically have some items which get an updated URL and I don't want the old URLs to work, because I want the old URLs to be directed to the new ones.

Comment: i added a 301 redirect, but the rewrite rule kicks in at the end and adds the variable ?id=number at the end of the redirected URL... any ideas on how to resolve?